# When is the django db connection made for the tasks in case async operations or django-q?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-q

I want to know when the db connection is made in case of async operations or django-q. My CONN_MAX_AGE = 0 and in the docs this is written,

> The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing the database connection at the end of each request.

I want to understand what a request mean in this case? Does it mean web requests only? If yes when is the db connection opened or closed in case of async operations or in case of django_q.